# Find magnetic flux linkage of a planar coil

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have got a planar spiral shown in the graph. C1 is the spiral body, and C2, C3 and C4 are the wires to make it a loop, where C2 is under the coil body.

[image: Spiral]

Assume I have known the geometric expressions of C1, C2, C3 and C4 in space.

For a single closed loop $l$, the magnetic flux linkage $\psi$ is equal to the magnetic flux $\Phi$ in terms of Magnetic vector potential $A$:

$$
\psi=\Phi=\oint_lA\cdot dl
$$

#### Question:

Now let's ignore the effect of average and inner lines of the pattern. So for the coil, can I tell that the magnetic flux linkage $\psi$ is:

$$
\psi=\oint_{C_1}A\cdot dC_1 + \oint_{C_2}A\cdot dC_2 + \oint_{C_3}A\cdot dC_3 + \oint_{C_4}A\cdot dC_4
$$
, where $A=\sum^4_{n=1}\oint_{C_n}\frac{\mu_0IdC_n}{4\pi R}$?

Comment: hint: both $A$ and $C_k; k=1..4$ are vectors

Comment: Yep. So you mean that I need to be aware of length addition rather than vector addition for the path integrals? In other words, I need to make it in the scalar form first and then add them together?

Comment: no. if $A$ and $dC$ are "vectors" then the angle $\alpha_k$ between them is relevant: $\mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{C_k} = AC_k cos(\alpha)$;  $\alpha_k$ is the angle between $A$ and the tangent of the curve $C_k$. Anyhow, your formula for the vector potential $A=\sum_{n=1}^{4}....$ is wrong.

Comment: @hyportnex I do not think $\mathbf{A}$ is wrong. If we have a look at the Magnetic Field $\mathbf{B}$ of each section, they can be added. $\mathbf{B}$ is the curl of $\mathbf{A}$. According to $\nabla \times (\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})=\nabla\times\mathbf{a}+\nabla\times\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{A}_{total}=\mathbf{A}_1+\mathbf{A}_2+\cdots$. In terms of vector line integral, piecewise smooth curve can be seen as the sum of each piece of curve said [here](https://sites.und.edu/timothy.prescott/apex/web/apex.Ch15.S3.html#ThmtheoremEnv1).

Comment: Your "$R$" in the denominator should depend on the index $n$ and the equation should be a vector one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. $R$ is the distance from the line $\mathbf{C}_n$ to a point in space. So is the adjustment needed to apply the index $n$ to $R$ instead of a universal $R$, where $\mathbf{C}_n$ is expressed as a vector function? And then the curl distribution applies to the magnetic flux linkage again. I can parameterise $\mathbf{C}_n$ so working out the integration of dot product between $\mathbf{A}$ and $d\mathbf{C}_n$ is easy to go. Do you think I am able to answer this question with this understanding?

Comment: yes, if you do all that then probably yes; good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help from @hyportnex.

It is noted that $R$ is the distance from the line to a point in space. Its expression is different for different curve piece so there should an index applied as $R_n$.

According to the property of [line integral over a vector field](https://sites.und.edu/timothy.prescott/apex/web/apex.Ch15.S3.html#ThmtheoremEnv1), the line integral of the union of the curve is the sum of the line integral of each curve piece.

For magnetic potential vector $\mathbf{A}$ to a point in space $(x, y, z)$:
$$
\mathbf{A}=\oint_C\frac{\mu I}{4\pi R}d\mathbf{C}=\sum^4_{n=1}\int_{C_n}\frac{\mu I}{4\pi R_n}d\mathbf{C}_n
$$
, where $R_n=|(x, y, z)-\mathbf{C}_n|$ and $\mathbf{C}_n$ can be parameterised with $t$.

The same applies to the magnetic flux linkage.
$$
\psi=\sum^4_{n=1}\int_{C'_n}\mathbf{A}\cdot d\mathbf{C'}_n
$$
, where $C'$ is the inner line if the width of the track takes account.